# Creating a field that has node values using FAPI

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I would like to use the Form API to create a form that uses a textfield that references all the current nodes as an autocomplete. Is there a way to added field using the FAPI that allows a user to type the node's title or ID and the field is validated by whether the node exists.

Comment: Is the form a custom module form? Might be easier to use an entity reference auto complete field, and then do your own validation function to determine whether the node exists or not

Comment: Yes this is a Custom Module Form. I'll look into entity reference fields. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is for a custom module, Drupal makes it quite easy to do an autocomplete field.

See a tutorial here... http://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-create-an-ajax-autocomplete-textfield-in-drupal-7/

You would then do a validation function to determine whether the entity exists, or you would only provide a list of existing entities in the first place.

If you are using the core fields, then try the entity reference module.